# Access port through subdomain

Tags: 18.04, server, java, dns

I have an **Ubuntu VPS** server where a Java application is running and available on port 8080.

I also registered a domain, and I'd like to access the 8080 port via a **subdomain** of this domain.

Let me give an example to be better understood:

My server's address is http://172.217.19.110/, and my domain is say `example.com`.

I can use my app on  http://172.217.19.110:8080, but I'd like to use it through `myapp.example.com`.

How can I do this? What shall I set up on the DNS provider, and what on the server-side?

Comment: Since you own the domain, an `A` DNS record should suffice: `myapp IN A 172.217.19.110`. After that you should be able to access your subdomain like `http://myapp.example.com:8080`.  (Obviously google.com was not a good example, so I edited your question too.) You haven't specified what web-server application you are using, so it is not possible to comment on the server side. In any case you have to specify the port number in the HTTP request or you can use redirection.

Comment: You are right, I set up the `A` DNS record and I also can access my server through `http://myapp.example.com:8080`. Actually I am trying to run www.keycloak.org, it is hosted  on JBoss/WildFly server.